# How many solutions to the rational equation?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> If $a$ and $b$ and $c$ are parameters, how many solutions for:
>
> $$\frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)} + \frac{(x-a)(x-c)}{(b-a)(b-c)}  + \frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)} = 1$$

I would say $3 \implies x = \{a, b, c\}$

But the answer is apparently $\infty$.

I am confused?

Comment: Of course it should be assumed that $a, b, c$ are distinct, otherwise the equation is undefined.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You observed that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are solutions. But if a polynomial of degree $\le 2$ has at least $3$ zeros, then it is the identically $0$ polynomial.

Comment: Hello sir, I am confused by this answer, the equation presented is a quadratic, so at most it should have $2$ zeros actually?

Comment: @GurkreetSandhu It means that all the terms cancel out.

Comment: The polynomial is not of degree $2$, it just at first sight **looks** like a polynomial of degree $2$. Because the equation at least three roots, when the equation is "simplified" by bringing everything to a common denominator, all the coefficients will turn out to be $0$. You can start verifying this by calculating the coefficient of $x^2$.  But that's the long way of doing it!

Comment: @AndréNicolas, but isn't $x$ the only variable?

Comment: If you simplify, the equation will become $0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x+0=0$, which has every number as a solution.  We took a shortcut towards seeing that, by using the fact that a polynomial equation of degree $m$ has at most $m$ solutions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, so simplifying gives $0$ as coefficients? But how? I tried simplifying but my coefficients are still not $0$?

Comment: Bring all to a common denominator $(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)$ by multiplying top and bottom of first by $b-c$, top and bottom of second by $c-a$, top and bottom of third by $a-b$. Then the coefficient of $x^2$ is $\frac{b-c+c-a+a-b}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}$.  This is $0$. Similarly we could with some pain calculate the coefficient of $x$, and the constant term, But that's the hard way to do it!

Comment: Very thoughtfully and instructive formulation. +1

Answer (score 2):

You are finding a second-degree polynomial whose graph goes through $(a,1),(b,1),(c,1)$ by [Lagrange's interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Such polynomial is unique, and it is clearly the constant $1$.

Comment: so three zeros right?

Comment: @GurkreetSandhu: in how may points the constant one equals one? Three?

Comment: So it is not a quadratic after all? But $f(x) = c$?